# After compiling bash it doesn't use ("/etc/bash.bashrc")

Tags: bash, yocto

In a yocto image I'm not getting /etc/bash.bashrc, even if I create it manually, bash isn't using it. How can I configure bash to use SYS_BASHRC as well.

In short, how can I compile bash to use system level bashrc file.

Comment: I assume that you mean it does not source that file when starting an _interactive_ shell (which is when it should read that file, not otherwise)? How exactly did you compile the shell?

Comment: I'm compiling bash in  yocto project, its poky layer have bash recipe, yes that's right. Its not sourcing file (/etc/bash.bashrc) with non login shell